# cannot create a connection string in C# web.config

Tags: .net, web-config

I am maintaining a site that was not built by me in ASP.NET.
it is built in C#.NET

the site access a Database using a DLL called `MegaTecDAL.dll`
(Note: i dont have the code for this dll, only the dll and PDB)

Recently, we need to move the site to another server with another database, and therefore need to change the connection string for the database.
**which i thought should be pretty Easy!**
i didn't find the connection string in the web.config or anywhere so,

I decompiled the Data Access Layer MegaTecDAL.DLL to get where the connection string is read from, and found the following (Notice: getzConnectionString)

```
namespace MegaTecDal.Properties
{
  [CompilerGenerated]
  [GeneratedCode("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "9.0.0.0")]
  internal sealed class Settings : ApplicationSettingsBase
  {
    private static Settings defaultInstance = (Settings) SettingsBase.Synchronized((SettingsBase) new Settings());

    public static Settings Default
    {
      get
      {
        Settings settings = Settings.defaultInstance;
        return settings;
      }
    }

    [DefaultSettingValue("Data Source=old.server.address.com;Initial Catalog=getz;User ID=aUserName;Password=StrongPassword")]
    [ApplicationScopedSetting]
    [SpecialSetting(SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public string getzConnectionString
    {
      get
      {
        return (string) this["getzConnectionString"];
      }
    }

    static Settings()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

I Realize, that the connection string is taken from the Default.
but i cant seem to find how to specify a new Value.

I Tried:

adding to the `web.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="getzConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=new.server.com;Initial Catalog=getz;User ID=aUserName;Password=StrongPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

also tried adding to `web.config`

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="getzConnectionString" value="Data Source=new.server.com;Initial Catalog=getz;User ID=aUserName;Password=StrongPassword"/>
</appSettings>
```

tried creating a file named `MegaTecDAL.dll.config` with the above sections and put it in the BIN/App_Data/App_Code & root folders but still, default connection string is called.

also tried adding Section group and section per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx

Anywhere i put it it does not do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to include the namespace of the ConnectionString you want to configure:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MegaTecDal.Properties.Settings.getzConnectionString" 
       connectionString="yourNewConnectionString"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
      name="getzConnectionString" 
      connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
      Catalog=getz;Persist Security Info=True;User 
      ID=userName;Password=password"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

This might helps you. Try to add this. for more details check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: i already did that in `web.config` and in `MegaTecDAL.dll.config` but not working

Comment: no, the site is connecting to the default database in the old server

Comment: I think you are reading it by wrong way. check my edited code

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i aint using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString.ToString();` because it is not my code that reading the Connection... i just needed to write the setting correctly.